# Show p element only when entire text can fit

Tags: javascript, html, css

When animating a div height, I need the elements to stack in, not gradually show.

Here is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/WzC3g/

```
<div class="introTextCont">
  <h2>Test</h2>
    <p class="introPara">Test 1</p>
    <p class="introPara">Test 2</p>
    <p class="introPara">Test 3</p>
</div>
```

As the height is increased you can see the top half of the text. What needs to happen is as the height is increaded the full p element is shown.

This is quite hard to explain, so any questions please ask.

Comment: that jsfiddle link it directing to their home page

Comment: Apologies. Please find the amended link in the question.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: [http://blog.steamshift.com/blog/2012/01/04/animation-blocks-with-jquery-deferred-and-pipe/](http://blog.steamshift.com/blog/2012/01/04/animation-blocks-with-jquery-deferred-and-pipe/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should give this a try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $items = jQuery(".introPara").css("visibility", "hidden");
    var $outer = jQuery('.introTextCont')
    $outer.animate({height: 100}, {
        duration: 2000,
        step: function(){
            if($items.length){
                var $test = $items.first();
                if($outer.height() > $test.offset().top + $test.outerHeight()){
                    $test.css("visibility", "");
                    $items = $items.slice(1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WzC3g/3/)

**EDIT** minor code update for the undefined $test, would update jsFiddle but the site seems unresponsive to me :(

Comment: Do you want to spam my console? :) `$test is undefined`

Comment: @Morpheus Yes.. that was my plan, I have updated the code for a different result though

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you have to transform the div and not to change its height.
To do that you have to use the 'transform:scaleY(value)' property in your css file.

for example:

```
div
{
transform: scaleY(2);
-ms-transform: scaleY(2); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scaleY(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scaleY(2); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: scaleY(2); /* Firefox */
}
```